# How can I find the hazelcast version in WSO2 IS binary

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, wso2-identity-server

I would like to understand the hazelcast version being used with git release 5.11 https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0
and where is it specified? Can I upgrade it to 4.2.4.wso2v1 to avoid the vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast is mainly used in the WSO2 [carbon-kernel](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/4.7.x) and simply upgrading 3.12.x to 4.2.x would result in issues as it is being a major version upgrade, there are set of API changes done from Hazelcast. This [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/13647) has tracked the effort of Hazelcast version upgrade on WSO2 products. You can port those fixes. Also note that **[WSO2 IS 6.0.0](https://wso2.com/identity-server/#)** has upgraded the Hazelcast.

Comment: Could you please share the link where you found out the version in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0

Comment: Also, How can we port the fixes shared in the wso2 binary?

Comment: From the License file you can find. https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/52f31a521fef8cfd94df7adfefeb1e1498979e90/LICENSE.txt#L172. Also the license can be found from the distribution itself.

Comment: The support fixes are sent by WSO2 for the customers on their demands. If you have the open source product, you will have to build the dependant modules by porting the fixes and patch the respective jar files.